# Redirect from 1 sub domain to another keeping the original url

Tags: .htaccess, plesk

I am using a plesk server and i have set up the following sub domains:

products.domain.co.uk
clientname.domain.co.uk

I want to point the following:

clientname.domain.co.uk/donations/id/
clientname.domain.co.uk/forms/id/

To products.domain.co.uk

And access the correct folder, pass in the id querysting but keep the original domain in the url.

I've tried .htaccess but i get SSL proxy error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this or is there another way to do it.

This is what i have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/donations
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://products.domain.co.uk/donations/ [P]
```

This is the errors i get from plesk log

Error
[SSL Proxy requested for clientname.domain.co.uk:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]

Error
HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for ....

Thanks

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Show us what you actually tried, instead of just saying _that_ you tried something and got an error.

Comment: Are both http hosts ("subdomains") hosted on the same http server? If so try not to use the proxy module but an internal rewriting rule.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution if this helps anyone else. I added the following in plesk under Apache & nginx Settings.

```
location ~ / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass https://subdomain1.domain.co.uk;
    proxy_redirect https://subdomain2.domain.co.uk https://$host/;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else.